# CEF Python Proxy Authentication

Tags: python, selenium, proxy-authentication, cefpython

Is there a way to add Proxy Authentication in CEF Python?

The best answer I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215691/cefsharp-proxy-authentication-required/42376097#42376097). The problem is that the code is written in C# and I couldn't manage to convert it to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEF Python currently does not support all the features of the referenced C# example.

You can set proxy using command line switches with the ["proxy-server"](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/api/CommandLineSwitches.md#proxy-server) switch, but this can be set only once during initialization when calling cef.Initialize. Chromium preferences (the SetPreference method in C#) which allow for setting options during runtime are not supported yet, this is to be implemented via [Issue #244](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/244). This isue is marked "next-release2", so this should be implemented in one of next releases (a few months usually).

CEF Python supports RequestHandler.[GetAuthCredentials](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/api/RequestHandler.md#getauthcredentials) callback. If you need GUI dialog for entering username/password then you need to implement this in your app using GTK/Qt or whatever GUI framework you use. There is no default implementation of auth credentials dialog in upstream CEF, applications need to implement such control on their own. On a side note there was a default implementation for auth dialogs on Windows in CEF Python 1 - but that's a very old version, code is [available here](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/tree/cefpython31/cefpython/cef1/http_authentication).