# How to authorize a proxy (login : password : ip : port : connection type) in winforms using CefSharp?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

As possible in CefSharp.WinForms authorize a proxy so that the browser page opens through a proxy.

There are no usage examples in the documentation, and there is little information on the Internet. Or are there other ways to use proxies in winforms for cefsharp?

```
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("load");
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");
        tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabPages.Count -1].Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(200, 30);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1];
        tabControl1.MouseClick += ShowContextMenuTabs;
        activeCurrentBrowser = chromeBrowser;
        chromeBrowser.AddressChanged += ChromeBrowser_AddressChanged;
        chromeBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += ChromeBrowser_LoadingStateChanged;
```

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-authentication

Comment: If you don't need to change the proxy st runtime you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888690/4583726